# Why we need "return" in recursions when we need to return a value?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, return

I'm so confused about the return keyword in recursion problems. For example, the following code is about checking whether a node is in a binary search tree. In contains method, may I know why we need the "return" in

```
return this.right.contains(data)
```

and

```
return this.left.contains(data)
```

?
I think without this return, whenever we just call

```
this.right.contains(data)
```

without return keyword, it will already return either "null" or this node based on the node data. Why do we need to put a return outside that again?

```
  if (this.data === data) {
        return this;
    }
```

and

```
  return null;
```

I think we already return the result to the outside layer. Besides when we use call back functions in javascript we didn't use return. I'm so confused. Thank you so much!

```
class Node {
 constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
 }
 insert(data) {
    if (data < this.data && this.left) {
        this.left.insert(data);
    } else if (data < this.data) {
        this.left = new Node(data);
    } else if (data > this.data && this.right) {
        this.right.insert(data)
    } else if (data > this.data) {
        this.right = new Node(data);
    }
 }
 contains(data) {
    if (this.data === data) {
        return this;
    }
    if (this.data < data && this.right) {
        return this.right.contains(data)
    } else if (this.data > data && this.left) {
        return this.left.contains(data)
    }
    return null;

 }
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript, a function that exits without a `return` always returns `undefined`. You need `return` because that's how the language works.

Comment: Yep.  If you're used to languages like Ruby that have an implied `return`, that's not how Javascript works.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I'm confused that whenever we call this.right.contains(data) , it will already return either "this" or "null", or call itself again, so it already contains return, why we put another return before call it?

Comment: @Ying when the function calls itself, it's a normal function call like any other. It doesn't just "jump to the top again" or something so that it could simply return later directly to the caller. No, when you `return` the result, you only return to the location of the recursive call, and code continues to run there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to make it clear by making your code more verbose and documented.

```
contains(data) {
    if (this.data === data) {
        // This node has the data return this
        return this;
    }
    if (this.data < data && this.right) {
        // We need to search the right subtree
        // when the result is back we take it and put it in a variable
        const rightSubtreeSearchResult = this.right.contains(data);

        // we have the result, we just need to return it
        return rightSubtreeSearchResult;

    } else if (this.data > data && this.left) {
        // Same as above but for left subtree
        // this time we just return the result directly without
        // putting it in a variable. The resulting behavior is just as above
        return this.left.contains(data);

    }
    // None of the above return null
    return null;

}
```

You are right about `this.right.contains(data)` returning a value but if you just call the method and not use its return value, the value is just there unused until the function execution is finished and then it's gone.

Simply put, if you don't `return`, the result of `left` and `right` search is not used and the function will always reach `return null` at the end and will return null, and not the correct result of search.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> I think we already return the result to the outside layer.

No.

That's literally the purpose of `return`: to do that. If you don't have a `return`, you're not doing that.

> Without return keyword, it will already return either "null" or this node based on the node data. Why do we need to put a return outside that again?

Not true in JavaScript. It may be true in some other programming languages.

> Besides when we use call back functions in javascript we didn't use return

Sometimes we do. It depends whether you need them to return a value.

So, to answer:

> Why we need “return” in recursions when we need to return a value?

Because that's what `return` does, hence the name.

Comment: Thank you so much! But inside the contains(data)  function we have a either return null or return this statement, so whenever we call contains(data) it will return null or this, or call itself which also contains the return null or itself, why we still need another return for its results?

Comment: To return the result of the function call? Otherwise you don't pass it to the caller. Neither `this` nor `null` is that result, so why you think they are sufficient?

Comment: If we find the node, and after the "return this", may I know who is the node returned to? And after return this.right.contains(data), who is the node returned to? Is it correct that after "return this" the node is passed to the current layer function? And return this.right.contains(data) is passing the node to its outer layer function? Or return this.right.contains(data)  is passing the node to where is calling contains(data)? So "return this" only ends the current function, not the out layers function? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code snippet in Java that I wrote to find a particular element in a binary search tree. (`find` method is being called by the root node of the binary search tree for the first time)

```
public boolean find(int data)
{
    if(data==this.getData())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(data<this.getData() && this.getLeftChild()!=null)
    {
        return this.getLeftChild().find(data);
    }
    if(data>=this.getData() && this.getRightChild()!=null)
    {
        return this.getRightChild().find(data);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Let's say I do not use `return` keyword in `return this.getLeftChild().find(data);`, and I write, `this.getLeftChild().find(data);`, then,
`this.getLeftChild().find(data);` calls itself, and checks `if(data==this.getData())`.
Let's say you get the match and the condition passes. Then note that

```
if(data==this.getData())
        {
            return true;
        }
```

will return `true` to the same function call `this.getLeftChild().find(data);`, whereas we want the code to return `true` to the place from where you called `find()` for the first time and have written the condition to print if the element is found or not.
If we do not use return keyword with `this.getLeftChild().find(data);`, then `true` is returned to it, and the control proceeds to check `if(data>=this.getData() && this.getRightChild()!=null)` and finally returns `false`, even though we have gotten the match. Consequently, you will get the output on the console that the element could not be found.

What you need to do is, exit the function as soon as you check that the data required does not match with the current node, and the data is less than the data of the current node. To do this, you use `return this.getLeftChild().find(data);` so that the `find()` function can be invoked with the left child of the current node being the root, without forming a long stack of function calls that you were doing by not using `return` keyword.

It's simple - once you have realized that the data passed is less than the data of the current node, and you need to check the left child of the current node, then why would you want to save the reference to

```
if(data>=this.getData() && this.getRightChild()!=null)
```

in a recursive stack when you would never check the right child of this current node.

Hope this helps.